# Objective C : How to send Email w/ attachment with iPhone OS v2.2.1?

Tags: objective-c, email-attachments

Objective C : How to send Email w/ attachment with iPhone OS v2.2.1 ?

I don't really want to setup a web server for this purpose as described in http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/06/sending-e-mail-attachments/

Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

iPhone OS 3.x has a library that allows you to do this. In 2.x you will need to either create your own library for sending email or find another library for sending email.

This blog post should get you going:
    http://vafer.org/blog/20080604120118

Comment: Hi many thanks, but it seems that Cocoa OSX library is different from iPhone library...

Comment: The easy way to include this code is by copying it straight into your xcode project (and fixing any errors and compiler warnings)